# Flutter : trigger a change of screen on a websocket message

Tags: android, mobile, websocket, dart, flutter

I'm currently working on a flutter app with a websocket.
I want to change the current screen with a `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/path')` in the method that is triggered by the websocket on a new message. The problem is that I don't have any `context` in this method.

So how to change the current screen from this method ?
I dont know if I'm thinking in the wrong way or if I just don't understand something.

Here is the method that is triggered on a new websocket message, his class is not a widget. This object is contained in every screen I create but his variable `_parent` is always set to match the active screen.

```
   onMessageReceived(data) {
        print("new message: " + data + " !");
        data = jsonDecode(data);
        data.forEach((key, value) {
          switch (key) {
            case "state":
              _parent.newState(value);
              break;
          }
      });
  }
```

Here is the method of the widget:

```
  newState(state){
    if(state == "start"){
      Navigator.pushNamed(, "/path");
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it necessary for you to navigate to other screen or you just want to show the data of the `websocket` ?

Comment: @MazinIbrahim I really want to navigate to an another screen.

Comment: @MaëlGassmann for this i think you need to call setState instead of new state to get the rerender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a stream for that. You can register the websocket response, and when it returns you can add it to the stream, and then on your screen you use a StreamBuilder to subscribe to the stream and navigate when needed. Something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

// Create a stream to receive the values
var webSocketStream = new BehaviorSubject<String>();

onMessageReceived(data) {
  print("new message: " + data + " !");
  data = jsonDecode(data);
  data.forEach((key, value) {
    switch (key) {
      case "state":
        // Write to the stream
        webSocketStream.add(value);
        break;
    }
  });
}

class CheckWebSocket extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<String>(
          // Subscribe to the stream
          stream: webSocketStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            // When the stream changes navigate
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data == "start") {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/path");
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

I used rxdart for that, because it makes dealing with streams simpler. I also recommend that you extract the code that reads the websocket to a separate class, I put everything in one file just to make it simpler to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
When I implemented that in my app, I got an error because it couldn't finish to build before navigating :
The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<String>(dirty, state:
I/flutter (32357): _StreamBuilderBaseState<String, AsyncSnapshot<String>>#489bf):
I/flutter (32357): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Comment: I forgot to return an empty container if the snapshot has no data, please try again.

Comment: Still, the same error is showing. Are you sure that you can navigate during build ?

Comment: Anyway, I found a solution : 
If snapshot has no data I just show a different scaffold than if he has data.
Thanks a lot.